# jQuery - image SRC

Tags: jquery

Am I doing something wrong?  #contactImg is not getting the src passed

```
var clickedImage = $('img.img_rightThumb').attr("src");
$('#contactImg').attr('src', clickedImage);
```

OK the selector I guess is bad...but I don't see how...

```
<? if ($this->profile['has_user_image']) { ?>
<img src="/images/users/<?= $this->profile['user_image'] ?>" width="114" class="img_rightThumb">
<? } else { ?>
<img src="/images/avatar.png" width="114" height="86" class="img_rightThumb">
<? } ?>
```

Comment: looks right to me. can we see the html?

Comment: The relevant part of the actual HTML from the page would be even better since we don't know what the PHP is doing and what actual HTML it generates.

Comment: Are you running your jQuery after the page has loaded successfully?  Or could it be that you're running it before the 'img.img_rightThumb' even exists yet?

Comment: it is possible that I do it before it exists, but I'm doing it the 5th time the element is clicked so I know it exists...oh I'm so confused...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not finding the image.  Try doing this to verify:

```
alert($('img.img_rightThumb').length);
```

If 0, the problem is the selector.  Post some HTML and we can help you with that.

Comment: yes Brian, you're right...it returned 0.  I added the HTML. thx

Comment: Huh, I would have thought that would work.  You could try $(".img_rightThumb") and just target the CSS class instead, at least as a test.  Alternatively, it could be because there is something invalid in the HTML, double check that attributes are properly closed and everything is well-formed, otherwise, that would have a similar result.

Comment: Also, what is this rendering out: <?= $this->profile['user_image'] ?>